# DataContext with MSAccess as Data Provider

Tags: ms-access, datacontext, dataprovider

I try use ms access as data provider but it give me exception.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataContext dx = new DataContext(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data\mail.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");
    }
```

The exception is

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
Message=Keyword not supported: 'provider'.
```

How could this happen ?

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I Found the solution. It bit tricky

First create oledbconnection with access data provider

```
IDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data\mail.accdb;Persist Security Info=True);
```

Last pass it to DataContext

```
DataContext dx = new DataContext(connection);
```